# Strange URL in the WordPress theme causing error when the site loads

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am facing a problem i.e.,  the site is taking more than usual time to load and showing an error when I inspected the page.
[image: The Error]
I tried searching for the link through the source code of the page, but I wasn’t able to locate where that link is actually present.
I don’t know where from this URL came, but I want to remove it, as it is not letting the page to load properly and fast.
Please tell me how to eliminate this error.
Details -

URL - [reportingall](https://reportingall.com)
Theme - Newspaper 8.5
Demo Module Installed - Gadgets
CMS - WordPress

I can provide more information, if required.
Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Try to increase max_execution_time in php.ini and see.

Comment: I want to remove that URL as it is of no use, so if you could tell me how to remove then it would be of great help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the page is trying to load image 52.jpg with the HTTP protocol instead of the HTTPS protocol your website is using. It seems your theme is trying to set your header to have a background image of 52.jpg, if you can change the path to be HTTPS instead of HTTP that should correct that issue. I know wordpress has plugins that can achieve this, or you can try to contact the creator of the theme if you don't have access to change the path.

[image]

If you're looking to just remove the code, you can try and find:

> background-image:url(http://192.168.0.120/wp_011_gadgets/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/52.jpg)

In your theme files and remove that, but if the theme is updated it will likely revert back and need to reapplied to each time you update the theme.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I checked the CSS file of the theme for the URL, but didn't find it.
Actually, the theme has multiple modules for different layouts and I tried installing other modules and none caused this error and this is the only module (Gadgets) out of all which is encountering this error.
BTW thanks for stopping by :)

Comment: If there are extensions they may have their own css file where the code is stored. Depending on the theme, this may also be in the header.php file itself. I would start looking in those places and go file by file to find this code.

I would also contact the creators of the theme, this may be a bug in the theme they are unaware of and can push an update out to fix.

Comment: I tried checking some of the files of that module, but still no success. Also, I have already posted about this error on their official forum and waiting for their reply on this matter.
Thanks!

Comment: Fixed it. It was a url posted all by itself in the theme panel of the site and I was going through the settings, so found it and fixed it.
Thanks for the efforts. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

it was easy to find this error

go to theme panel -> misc -> background -> mobile menu/search background -> then change http to https and save.

img : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfHGS.jpg

Done.

Comment: Fixed my Newspaper theme. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS rule on your page which as a selector has `.td-search-background` and which contains a `background-image` setting whose URL is linked to a server with the IP address `192.168.0.120` . The image is called "52.jpg".

This looks like a local address - maybe even your own computer - which wasn't converted when you moved the WP installation from the test server to the performance server.

A comment above these CSS rules says `<!-- Header style compiled by theme -->` . So you should either search for settings in your theme where the server address is defined, or you should search for CSS files/settings created by your theme which contain this rule and change the URL there.

Comment: I tried searching for the background image in the CSS file but didn't find it.
I didn't move the wp installation from the test server to the performance server, instead I directly installed WordPress on AWS server and I never encountered such an error before.